# ANTLR4 + Python: Get object returned by parser rule

Tags: python, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have written multiple parser rules in the following format

```
somerule returns [Clause c]: ... ;
```

and now I would like to write a python class called `Parser` that will return the `Clause` object when its method `parse` is called. I have started with

```
class Parser:

def __init__(self, path):
    self.lexer = TemporalLogicLexer(FileStream(path))
    self.stream = CommonTokenStream(self.lexer)
    self.parser = TemporalLogicParser(self.stream)

def parse(self):
    # What should I do here? This method should return the parsed Clause object
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to finish the code?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - I have already found the answer:

```
def parse(self):
    return self.parser.somerule().c
```